# Update in LINQ to Objects

Tags: linq-to-objects

How to do an update in LINQ to Objects. Trying convert SQL to Linq

```
Quality
        (
          TransactionID int,
          Quantity float,
          MaterialID int,
          ProductID int,
          ParameterID int,
          ParameterValue float,
          TotalTonnes float
        )
```

How to convert below SQL to linq:

```
UPDATE  Q1
            SET     TotalTonnes = ( SELECT  SUM(Quantity)
                                    FROM    @Quality Q2
                                    WHERE   Q1.ParameterID = Q2.ParameterID
                                            AND ( ( Q1.MaterialID = Q2.MaterialID )
                                                  OR ( Q1.MaterialID IS NULL
                                                       AND Q2.MaterialID IS NULL
                                                     )
                                                )
                                            AND ( ( Q1.ProductID = Q2.ProductID )
                                                  OR ( Q1.ProductID IS NULL
                                                       AND Q2.ProductID IS NULL
                                                     )
                                                )
                                  )
            FROM    @Quality Q1
```

Thanks

Comment: If there's a database on the other end, you're not working with LINQ to Objects. It could be LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, or something else, but the difference actually does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would do updates imperatively. Something like this:

```
foreach (var q1 in Q1)
{
    q1.TotalTonnes = (from q2 in Q2
                      where q1.ParameterID == q2.ParameterID
                        && q1.MaterialID == q2.MaterialID
                        && q1.ProductID == q2.ProductID
                      select q2.Quantity).Sum();
}
```

Note that the double null checks aren't required because of the way null comparisons are handled in C#. (i.e. `(null == null)` is true)

Answer (score 0):

For better performance and what I think is cleaner code you can use the ToLookUp method.  If Q2 is large this will be much better performance as there is no nested loops.

```
var Q2LookUp = 
    Q2.ToLookUp(q2 => new {q2.ParameterId, q2.MaterialID, q2.ProductId});
foreach (var q1 in Q1)  
{
    q1.TotalTonnes = 
        Q2Lookup[new {q1.ParameterId, q1.MaterialID, q1.ProductId}]
            .Sum(q2 => q2.Quantity);
}
```